# Nokia Base Maps return Error 404 when run from ArcGIS Flex Viewer

Tags: apache-flex, arcgis, here-api

We have a GIS website that uses arcGIS FlexViewer to display base maps. ArcGIS Flexviewer 2.7 sets nokia Normal, Nokia Hybrid and Nokia Satelite as some of the web tiled base maps to be offered.

Have these maps been retired or migrated to a web server? See the links below. I ran Fiddler to capture traffic and see http error 404 Page Not found when our IE 7.5 website attempts to load the base maps.

We switched to Google Maps V 3 base map as an alternative. ESRI has discontinued devleopment of arcGIS Viewer. The value of the subdomain value is 1, 2,3 and 4.

Nokia Normal:

> http://{subDomain}.maps.nlp.nokia.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/{level}/{col}/{row}/256/png8?lg=ENG&token=kMdQI9U0KU_OszxB8DZHoA&app_id=oPWEwjDmOc6AEYUPEjVI"

Nokia Hybrid:

> http://{subDomain}.maps.nlp.nokia.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/hybrid.day/{level}/{col}/{row}/256/png8?lg=ENG&app_id=oPWEwjDmOc6AEYUPEjVI&token=kMdQI9U0KU_OszxB8DZHoA&xnlp=CL_JSMv2.2.4,SID_40159F64-826F-48B6-B47C-B11C2AF70951"

Nokia Satellite:

> http://{subDomain}.maps.nlp.nokia.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/satellite.day/{level}/{col}/{row}/256/png8?lg=ENG&token=kMdQI9U0KU_OszxB8DZHoA&requestid=ema18021_FlexViewer&app_id=oPWEwjDmOc6AEYUPEjVI"

Nokia Terrain:

> http://{subDomain}.maps.nlp.nokia.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/terrain.day/{level}/{col}/{row}/256/png8?lg=ENG&token=kMdQI9U0KU_OszxB8DZHoA&requestid=ema18021_FlexViewer&app_id=oPWEwjDmOc6AEYUPEjVI"

Answer (score 0):

HERE Maps is no longer a Nokia company, please move to correct here.com domains, examples available on following link 
https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/map-tile/map-tile-normal

Documentation link is as follows :
https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/overview.html